# HtmlService Sites gadget dynamic height

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm inserting an Apps Script Html Service gadget into a google site. Is there some way to make the site page height and script container height dynamic to avoid scroll bars on the inserted gadget?

Comment: I haven't worked in Google Sites for awhile now, so, does it accept JS? If no, there's probably no way and you should consider migrating to a published HTML gas. It's a much more powerful system, if you have HTML and JS knowledge you'll work pretty fast with it.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible, it would be in the:

[Apps Script Sites Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/)

But I don't see any method for adding or editing a Gadget.

The only way I'm guessing that this might be possible, is if you got the HTML out of the current page:

```
var site = SitesApp.getSite("example.com", "mysite");
var page = site.getChildren()[0];
Logger.log(page.getHtmlContent());
var pageHTML = page.getHtmlContent();
```

edited the HTML to change in code with string functions,

```
var stringPageHTML = page.getHtmlContent();
//Find the HTML string you want to change, and change
//it with JavaScript string functions
var newHTML = "New HTML";
```

Delete the page:

```
page.deletePage();
```

Add a new page:

```
page.createWebPage(title, name, newHTML)
```

Comment: Proposing to re-create the Sites page as the user visits or some time after inserting the web app? Not following this.

Comment: The height of my script webapp expands and contracts as it's being used. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, the gadget iframe height / width had to be about 50 pixels larger than the web app for no scroll bars to appear. When inserting the web app into the gadget it asks you for height in fixed pixels not a percentage. So I think getting the Sites page to be fully responsive is out the question.